# Domain ID Authentciation Timing

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory

Window Server 2008 R2 is my Domain Controller i.e Active Directory

I Need to find out when does Particular Domain ID has been used for authentication.
I know that from 'Active Directory Users and Computerss' > Domain ID, in Attribute Editor Tab, we can find see - 'Last Logon' & 'LastLogon TimeStamp' but it is only updated when user login through some Domain System right? and replicated at interval of 14 days to other Domain Controller.

But, If user has used his/ her Domain ID authentication in third party application to fetch LDAP information or for login through Sonicwall Global VPN Connection, than i think this LastLogon time stamp does not get updated, because he is not logging, but just using it's authentication, to validate it's credential.
If yes, than how to find out last authentication time for that particular domain ID

Regards,
Param

Answer (score 0):

From ["The LastLogonTimeStamp Attribute" – "What it was designed for and how it works"](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2009/04/15/the-lastlogontimestamp-attribute-what-it-was-designed-for-and-how-it-works/).

> It is important to note that the intended purpose of the `lastLogontimeStamp` attribute [is] to help identify inactive computer and user accounts. [It] is not designed to provide real time logon information. With default settings in place the lastLogontimeStamp will be 9-14 days behind the current date.
>
> If you are looking for more “real-time” logon tracking you will need to query the Security Event log on your DC’s for the desired logon events i.e. 528 –Windows XP2003 and earlier or 4624 Windows Vista2008 . See this [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericfitz/archive/2008/08/20/tracking-user-logon-activity-using-logon-events.aspx) by Eric Fitzgerald for more info. (I think he knows something about auditing)
>
> IMO your best bet for near real-time data is to use an event log collection service to gather all domain controller security event logs to a centralized database. You can then query a single database for the desired logon events. Microsoft’s solution for security event log collection is [Audit Collection Services](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb381373.aspx). There are many 3rd party solutions as well.